# How to get title and remove between certain characters from markdown files

Tags: bash, sed

I have markdown files and one example is the following:

```
---
id: http
title: Title can be anything
sidebar_label: HTTP API
---
import Tabs from '@theme/Tabs';
import TabItem from '@theme/TabItem';

export let Bubble = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{ display: 'flex', fontFamily: 'monospace', borderRadius: '3px', backgroundColor: '#ddd', display: 'inline', padding: '5px'}}>
                {item}
            </div>
            <div className=twentypx/>
        </div>
    );
}

## This title can be anything too
bla bla
```

Each file has different content between `---` and `##`. I'd like to get the title and, I'd like to replace from `---` to above `##` with `# Title can be anything`

So the desired end result should be:

```
# Title can be anything

## This title can be anything too
bla bla
```

Please note that title is different in other files.
How can I do this with Bash?

Comment: I added at the end as desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

With a Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -0pe 's/.*^title:\s*([^\n]+\n).*(?=## General)/# $1\n/ms' file

# HTTP API

## General & Auth
bla bla
```

Comment: Other files have different title. I need to get characters after title: .

Comment: Post edited accordingly

Comment: General can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/title:/{s/[^ ]* (.*)/\1/;h};/^-/,/^}/d;/^$/{x;s/^/# /;G}' input_file
# HTTP API

## General & Auth
bla bla
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.